# Java - How to Extract Certain Portions of Bits Using Bit Mask?

Tags: java, bit, bitmask

This is the first time I am looking at bitwise operations and bit mask. I have seen some examples using C and C++, but I am looking for clarification using Java.

I have the following 32-bit string

0000 00**00 101**0 0110 0011 1000 0010 0000

But I want to extract bits 21 through 25 in bold (00101) and ignore everything else. In the end, I want my output result to be integer 5 (0101 in binary)

Using bit mask, what approach I could use to get just that bit portion as my output result?

Comment: Shift the number right by 21 bits; `&` with `0x1F`.

Comment: Java has a bit wise shift operator >> so just shift you rbits down to the lowest bits (i.e. shift them right 21 bits.

Answer (score 3):

If you really have a `String`, take the two substrings (**`00`** and **`101`**), concatenate them, and use `Integer.parseInt` with a radix of two:

```java
int bits = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(7, 9) + str.substring(10, 13), 2);
```

---

If you have an `int`, use a logical right shift, then use `&` with a bit mask (`0b` signifies binary notation).

```java
int bits = (n >>> 21) & 0b11111;
```